# why jvm -XX:+EliminateAllocations fail

Tags: java, jvm, jit

OnStackTest.java

```
public class OnStackTest {

    public static void alloc() {
        User u = new User();
        u.id = 5;
        u.name = "test";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        long b = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(50);
            alloc();
        }
        long e = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(e - b);
    }
}
```

User.java

```
public class User {
    public int id = 0;

    public String name = "";

    public User() {
    }
    public User(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

JVM flags
`-server -Xmx10m -Xms10m -XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis -XX:+PrintGC -XX:-UseTLAB  -XX:+EliminateAllocations`

use `jmap -histo`

It is found that the user object has been created all the time on the heap. In theory, we should not replace the user object with scalar, and do not create the object on the heap?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this option is enabled by default, so explicitly enabling will not make any difference.

Comment: Related: [What does the java option -XX:-EliminateAllocations do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38613390/what-does-the-java-option-xx-eliminateallocations-do)

Comment: I know this parameter is on by default, but the result is not correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DoEscapeAnalysis` and `EliminateAllocations` flags are enabled by default - there is no need to set them explicitly.

`EliminateAllocations` flag is specific to C2 compiler, it is declared in [c2_globals.hpp](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/b36870ac13f5/src/share/vm/opto/c2_globals.hpp#l485). But in your test the method is not even compiled by C2 for a long time. Add `-XX:+PrintCompilation` flag to make sure:

```
    ...
   1045   84       3       java.lang.StringBuffer::<init> (6 bytes)
   1045   85  s    3       java.lang.StringBuffer::toString (36 bytes)
   1045   86       3       java.util.Arrays::copyOf (19 bytes)
  15666   87     n 0       java.lang.Thread::sleep (native)   (static)
  15714   88       3       OnStackTest::alloc (20 bytes)
 311503   89       4       OnStackTest::alloc (20 bytes)
 311505   88       3       OnStackTest::alloc (20 bytes)   made not entrant
```

This shows that `alloc` is compiled by C1 (tier 3) after 15 seconds. A method needs to be called several thousands of times before it is considered for re-compilation by C2. Given 50 ms delay between iterations, this does not happen soon enough. In my experiment, `alloc` is compiled by C2 only after 5 minutes of running.

C2-compiled method no longer contains allocations.
I verified this with `-XX:CompileCommand="print,OnStackTest::alloc"`

```
  # {method} {0x0000000012de2bc0} 'alloc' '()V' in 'OnStackTest'
  #           [sp+0x20]  (sp of caller)
  0x0000000003359fc0: sub     rsp,18h
  0x0000000003359fc7: mov     qword ptr [rsp+10h],rbp  ;*synchronization entry
                                                ; - OnStackTest::alloc@-1 (line 4)

  0x0000000003359fcc: add     rsp,10h
  0x0000000003359fd0: pop     rbp
  0x0000000003359fd1: test    dword ptr [0df0000h],eax
                                                ;   {poll_return}
  0x0000000003359fd7: ret
```

BTW, I suggest to use [JMH](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh) for such kind of tests. Otherwise it's too easy to fall into one of common benchmarking pitfalls. Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38521299/will-the-jit-optimize-new-objects) that also tries to measure the effect of allocation elimination, but does it wrong.

Comment: when I change the JVM parameters
`-XX:+PrintCompilation -XX:CompileCommand="print,OnStackTest::alloc"`
```
      12944   69     n 0       java.lang.Thread::sleep (native)   (static)
      12994   70       3       com.zby.learn.jvm.OnStackTest::alloc (20 bytes)
      12994   71       3       com.zby.learn.jvm.User::<init> (16 bytes)
     271252   72       4       com.zby.learn.jvm.OnStackTest::alloc (20 bytes)
     271252   70       3       com.zby.learn.jvm.OnStackTest::alloc (20 bytes)   made not entrant
```

Comment: This shows that alloc is compiled by C2 (tier 4) after 271252 millisecond and `made not entrant` appeared,then run `jamp -histo | findstr User`,User objects no longer grow.But that's because the JIT compiler optimizes the zombie code, it has nothing to do with `-XX:+PrintCompilation`.
BTW,What's the meaning of `-XX:CompileCommand="print,OnStackTest::alloc"`?

Comment: @learninJava This prints the assembly code for the method, where I took the above snippet from.